# why is PHP missing from the web platform installer?

Tags: php, iis

I'm running Windows8 with IIS8. I'm trying to install PHP using the web platform installer 4.5.

I used these steps.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2819022

The only versions of PHP I see are for IIS Express...I need it for real IIS.

Anyone else see this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to go into Options in WebPI, and change the web server from IIS Express to IIS. Then you get all the full IIS packages.

Answer (score -1):

I have often wondered this myself, but the answer to your question lies within PHP documentation.

https://www.php.net/windows

It is a little bit tempermental after setup but take that when you get to it.